# Can't add GST Tax on top of Stripe Checkout Price

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I'm struggling to add GST (Tax) to my stripe checkout. totalBill is the final amount, but I want to add 10% GST (Australian Tax). What do I need to do to have it displayed and calculated in my Stripe Checkout?

Thanks in advance, pulling my hair out over this one!

```
const product = await stripe.products.create({
      name: `Service for ${name} + GST`,
      tax_code: "txcd_99999999",
    });
    const price = await stripe.prices.create({
      currency: "aud",
      unit_amount: totalBill * 100,
      product: product.id,
    });
    if (price) {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email: email,
        name: name,
        address: {
          line1: addressLine1,
          city: addressCity,
          state: addressState,
          postal_code: addressPostalCode,
          country: addressCountry,
        },
      });
      if (customer) {
        session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
          payment_method_types: ["card"],
          line_items: [
            {
              price: price.id,
              quantity: 1,
            },
          ],
          customer: customer.id,
          customer_update: {
            address: "auto",
          },
          mode: "payment",
          success_url: `URL`,
          cancel_url: "URL",
        });
        const customerid = customer.id;
        customerStripeURL = `https://dashboard.stripe.com/customers/${customerid}`;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a [tax rate](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tax_rates/create) for GST first, and specify the resulting tax rate ID in the [line_times.tax_rates](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-tax_rates) during checkout session creation.

Comment: Thank you! I added the following code, if anyone is looking for the code answer

 const gstTaxRate = await stripe.taxRates.create({
      display_name: "GST", // Display name for the tax rate
      description: "Australian Goods and Services Tax", // Description of the tax rate
      jurisdiction: "AU", // Jurisdiction for the tax rate (in this case, Australia)
      percentage: 10,
      inclusive: false, // Specify whether the tax is inclusive or exclusive
    });

Then add tax_rates: [gstTaxRate.id], to line items